# Error in rxjs after update angular to version 7.0

Tags: angular, typescript

Recently I updated my angualr to version 7. but when I wanted to run ng serve I received following error :

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(project).
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(project).
at MergeMapSubscriber._registry.compile.pipe.operators_1.concatMap.validatorResult [as project] (.../node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace.js:215:42)
at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (.../node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:69:27)
at MergeMapSubscriber._next (.../node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:59:18)
at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (.../node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (.../node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:92:26)
at InnerSubscriber._next (.../node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (.../node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
at MapSubscriber._next (.../node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/map.js:55:26)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (.../node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (.../node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:86:26)
```

How can I fix this problem??

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an RxJS problem, but rather some schema validation problem in the CLI. I'd bet that your angular.json file as a problem.

Comment: Ok, what should I do?

Comment: Generate a brand new project with the CLI, and check for differences between the new project's angular.json file and yours. See which whanges you might have made (or forgot to make when upgrading) to the CLI configuration in your git history. Port the relevant details of your configuration (packagejson, angular.json). Tell us precisely what you did to migrate from version ??? to version 7.0.